# Properties vs. Getters and Setters

Tags: python, properties, init

It has been considered as a "[horrible scenario](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)" to update OurClass so that "OurAtt" is a value between 0 and 1000:

```
class OurClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.OurAtt = a

x = OurClass(10)
print(x.OurAtt)
```

Now, my question is why do we rely on the **@property**? Is it because of code legibility or there is some other reason; since we can well do the checks under the __init__() method?

```
class OurClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        if a < 0:
            self.OurAtt = 0
        elif a > 1000:
            self.OurAtt = 1000
        else:
            self.OurAtt = a
```

Comment: I would recommend reading [Python @property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you perform checks in the `__init__` method **does not guarantee that the value cannot be altered later** to an invalid value.

For example:

```
x = OurClass(10)
x.OurAtt = -20
```

We thus want to **run the test every time the `ourAtt` value is set**. We can do this with:

```
class OurClass:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.OurAtt = a

    @property
    def OurAtt(self):
        return self._OurAtt

    @OurAtt.setter
    def OurAtt(self,a):
        if a < 0:
            self._OurAtt = 0
        elif a > 1000:
            self._OurAtt = 1000
        else:
            self._OurAtt = a
```

Furthermore it allows to make the code more readable: every setter checks whether one specific value is valid. This is usually a better approach than checking all values in the same method, since if we alter the specifications of one value, we only have to modify the corresponding *setter*.

Another advantage is that validation is done in a transparent matter: you do not have to change an attribute into a "setter method": for the user, it just looks like he/she alters an attribute. You can thus later in the process - when users already make use of the attribute - decide to add some validation without changing the interface.

Finally it is more declarative and thus usually more "*Pythonic*".